# IBuffer in UWP for TCP messages

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, uwp

I need to  transfer a string over TCP connection. For this I serializable my object(over 10000 line list) in one stroke, without Intended. But large string won't transfer(As I understood due to buffer size). So MSDN, on this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) say me to use IBuffer for transfer my divided stroke. Here is a code:

```
// More efficient way to send packets.
// This way enables the system to do batched sends
IList<IBuffer> packetsToSend = PreparePackets();
var outputStream = stream.OutputStream;

int i = 0;
Task[] pendingTasks = new Tast[packetsToSend.Count];
foreach (IBuffer packet in packetsToSend)
{
 pendingTasks[i++] = outputStream.WriteAsync(packet).AsTask();
}
 // Now, wait for all of the pending writes to complete
  await Task.WaitAll(pendingTasks);
```

What is the method PraparePackets()? How to prepare packets from my stroke?

**Edit:** I've found solution with DataReader and DataWriter, which has written in Albahari.(End of 16 chapter).

Comment: it seems like you already resolved your issue. For looking clearly or convenient more people, you can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution with DataReader and DataWriter, which has written in Albahari.(End of 16 chapter).